# Getting Codeigniter to work on localhost with xampp

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

I have Netbeans, Codeigniter, and xampp setup on a Windows 7 machine and I am simply trying to call up a simple object to display hello world.

I keep getting the Object not found error after exhausting many tutorials.  When I run my script it uses the following url

```
http://localhost/project1/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/application/controllers/hello.php
```

So xampp is working fine when I call up localhost/xampp from my browser although im not sure what else needs to be configured.

I've tried many different base urls although currently my `config.php` has it set as follows `$config['base_url'] = '';`

I'm a newbie just trying to get things setup so I can start working on projects but can't get past this for days.

Comment: did you try: http://localhost/project1/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/index.php/hello ?

Answer (score 14):

That's not how CodeIgniter URLs work.  It should be:

```
http://path/to/codeigniter/index.php/<controller>/<function>/<param>
```

So, in your case, it should be:

```
http://localhost/project1/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/index.php/hello
```

`$config['base_url']` should be set to the `index.php`, so it should be:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project1/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/index.php';
```

DOCS: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html